# Discount for subscription plans?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce3

In the CP there are discounts that are applied to products in cart.

Is there an option in the CP to apply discounts to subscription plans or would this need to be done by creating a module? Just need confirmation before building a custom module as the docs doesn't specify such a option.

Using: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-stripe

Commerce: Latest to this date

CraftCMS: Latest to this date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Not yet" is the short answer. https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/295